# Getting image with Last.fm API

Tags: javascript, api, last.fm

I can already get the track and artist for last played track from my Spotify account. Code:

```
    $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=xxxxxx&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&limit=2&nowplaying=false&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
        var html = '';
        var counter = 1;
        $.each(data.recenttracks.track, function(i, item) {
            if(counter == 1) {
            html += '<span>' + item.name + '<br /> ' + item.artist['#text'] + '</span>' + item.image;
            }
            counter++
        });

        $('.listening-to').append(html);

    });
```

But item.image yields:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `item.image[3]['#text']` instead of `item.image`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the album image isn't included in the response from the API request you're making (user's recent tracks). Or if it is, you're trying to access the wrong JSON property. Try double-checking the raw JSON response to see if the album image URI is in there. If it isn't, you'll have to make a separate call to the API just to pull more detailed album info.